# d3 javascript: reading json file

Tags: d3.js

I want to write a code snippet in d3js that will read a json file, and display a simple bar chart based on the contents of the json file. My json file, `mydata.json`, is:

```
[
    {“name”: “Apollo_Diomedes”, “age”: 300},
    {“name”: “Bjorn_the_Fellhanded”, “age”: 900},
    {“name”: “Jonah_Orion”, “age”: 500}
]
```

d3js code snippet, from `index.html`:

```
<body>
<script>
d3.json("mydata.json", function(data) {

    var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 500)

    canvas.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("width", function(x) { return x.age; })
            .attr("height", 45)
            .attr("y", function(x, i) { return i * 50; })
            .attr("fill", "blue")
    });
</script>
</body>
```

I'm using d3 v4:
`<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>`.

I've tried opening the `index.html` file directly, and opening a local server and navigating to `localhost:8080` as directed [here](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki); both just show me a blank screen. Both `index.html` and `mydata.json` are saved in the same folder on my desktop.

For those interested, it's actually [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2S1AbEWX85o&index=10&list=PL6il2r9i3BqH9PmbOf5wA5E1wOG3FT22p) slightly outdated youtube tutorial; it runs d3 v3.

P.S. I can read in info from a CSV, but not json.

Comment: you have a problem with parsing the JSON data. The problem is in your JSON formatted data not how you call it. i just replace your “ with ' and it works just fine 
`[
    {"name": "Apollo_Diomedes", "age": 300},
    {"name": "Bjorn_the_Fellhanded", "age": 900},
    {"name": "Jonah_Orion", "age": 500}
]`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have problems with parsing the JSON data. Try replacing your quotation marks to the English ones (").

And in general, always check the console log of your Web browser. I am certain that you will some error printed there.